# Preserve React component state with Relay.setVariables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relay

I'm working on an application using **React** with **Relay** and **GraphQL**. I've run into an issue where I need to preserve a component's state while changing relay variables.

For example, say I have the component state:

```
state = {
  to: '',
  from: '',
  body: '',
  ...
}
```

And I have a Relay container with the following fragment and variables:

```
initialVariables: {
  to: '',
  from: '',
},
fragments: {
  viewer: () => Relay.QL`
    fragment on viewer {
      ...
      thread(to: $to, from: $from)
    }
  `
}
```

The component has text fields for the **to** and **from** fields, with an *onChange* handler which also updates the relay variables

```
onChange = e => {
  const to = e.target.value;

  this.setState({ to });
  this.props.relay.setVariables({ to });
}
```

This causes the query to execute again, the component re-renders, and I lose any changes to my current component state.

The only solution I've found thus far is to keep this state in a parent component, and pass down the values and onChange handlers as props, but it would be nice to keep this all in the same component.

**How can I call relay.setVariables without losing state?**

Comment: If you store the inputs `to` and `from` in relay variables, why do you need to store them in component state as well?

Comment: Good point, I guess I don't need to, but I still lose body in the state after calling setVariables. This is also just a basic example, I am storing various other fields in the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [`setVariables`](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-container.html#setvariables) and `setState` take an optional second argument to run after the state has *actually* updated.

I *think* you want:

```
this.props.relay.setVariables({ to }, () => this.setState({ to }));
```

but perhaps the inverse.